# What are these instruments? adkhor-pondour, damkech, enietkoutchine, joujjalka, sybyzgui, taura

Tags: instruments

I'm trying to find info on some instruments from an ethnographic set of music from the former USSR area.  Namely:

- adkhor-pondour - Chechen
- damkech - Azerbaijani
- enietkoutchine - Siberian
- joujjalka - Siberian
- sybyzgui - Kazakh
- taura - Latvian

Can anyone help ID anything about these?  Google has been of no help with them.

Edit:   Collecting the answers here for anyone looking in the future:

- adkhor-pondour: a possible mistransliteration of атхок-пондар, which appears to be a Chechen violin.
- damkech - a balaban
- <s>enietkoutchine</s> - not an instrument
- joujjalka - English: Zhuzhalka.  Siberian instrument, some sort of whirligig
- sybyzgui: English: sybyzgy.  a Kazakh, Kyrgyz and Mongol people sideblown flute traditionally played by shepherds and horse herders, made from apricot wood or the wood of mountain bushes.
- taura - English: taure.  A birch trumpet

Comment: Google is probably of no help because those seem to be the french spellings of the names of the instruments. One useful result is this french release of a cd set which features several of the instruments: https://www.edmu.fr/2014/08/voyage-en-urss.html

Comment: Yes, that's the set I'm working on.  I've been unable to find any other language's name for those instruments if they're not latinized versions of the local names.

Comment: The CD booklet apparently has "historical essays/dictionary of instruments in French and English" according to discogs.com. You can find the booklet (including the English part) online, e.g. https://albumartcovers.wordpress.com/2014/08/22/voyage-en-urss-1-russie-ukraine-bielorussie/

Comment: Yes, but it unfortunately doesn't cover every last instrument on there.

Comment: Don't forget that transliteration depends on the target language: Tchaïkovski, Tschaikowski, Čajkovski, Ciajkovskij, Tsjajkovski.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some answers:

[Phandar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phandar) and related [Panduri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panduri). **adkhor-pondour** seems to be a mistake for **атхок-пондар** which is mentioned briefly [here](https://docplayer.ru/42845815-Ezhemesyachnyy-literaturno-hudozhestvennyy-zhurnal.html).

[Sybyzgy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sybyzgy)

[Taure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birch_trumpet)

[Zhuzhalka](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%96%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0) (a whirligig)

[Balaban](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balaban_(instrument)) seems to be what you want for **damkech**. According to [this document](http://irs-az.com/new/pdf/201412/1418906899631568121.pdf): "Balabans are played by both amateur musicians and professionals. in solo performances, two performers appear before the audience: one - **usta** (master) – performs a melody and the second one - **damkesh** (assistants) – supports him with a constant low sound of the same height."

In my opinion, **enietkoutchina** is not an instrument but a transliteration of the name **Нутэтэин** in genitive case, with **k** being the transliterator's attempt to represent the glottal stop in the Chukchi language. This is a performer's name, and appears together in your source with another performer's name **Умка** (**Oumka**).

Comment: Thanks!  That'll let me finish representing the instruments on https://musicbrainz.org/release/ebe60f93-8f0c-44b5-b792-8e52e1d64aab as correctly as possible, and gives me a start towards getting the missing instruments added to the system.  :)